# Docker container going down

Tags: docker

I have 3 containers who communicates and exchange data through each other by sending jobs via RabbitMQ.
Since yesterday, the last container to be executed in the workflow (`encoder_aggregatore`) exits as soon as it is built up:

```
 $docker-compose up -d --build
  [..]
 $docker ps -a
 0f521c4260a5        encoder_my-pre-encoder   "python main.py"         About an hour ago   Up 20 minutes                                                                       encoder_my-pre-encoder_1
 72c3f5a2aa9c        encoder_aggregatore        "python /src/main.py"    18 hours ago        Exited (1) 20 minutes ago                                                           encoder_aggregatore_1
 dd9104e888ee        encoder_classificatore     "python /src/main.py"    20 hours ago        Up 20 minutes               0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp                                  encoder_classificatore_1
9
```

More info:

```
$docker inspect 72c3f5a2aa9c
```

The output is [here](https://pastebin.com/Dvrwe7rX).

I'm totally a newby in Docker. I do not know if it can help but I noticed that, if I edit the code of the "broken" container, the new code is compiled but executed on the "old" data job sent by container `encoder_my-pre-encoder`. I guess then that, for some reason, their communication broke.
Could you give me some hints on what it is going on?

EDIT 1:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  files:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ./file/input:/file/input
      - ./file/output:/file/output

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:5.1.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/grafana/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    environment:
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource
      - GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED=false
    depends_on: 
      - prometheus

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports: 
      - 9090:9090

  aggregatore:
    build: aggregatore/.
    volumes:    
      - ./aggregatore:/src
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]    
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  classificatore:
    build: classificatore/.
    volumes:    
      - ./classificatore:/src
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports: 
      - 8080:5000      
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  my-pre-encoder:
    build: mpeg-pre-encoder/.
    volumes:
      - ./my-pre-encoder:/src
      - ./gabac_encoder:/src/gabac_encoder
    volumes_from: 
      - files    
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "cluster_status"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 20
```

aggregatore container log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 94, in <module>
    rabbit.wait_for_job(worker)
  File "/src/util.py", line 75, in wait_for_job
    self.channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1822, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 758, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 521, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1445, in _dispatch_events
    evt.body)
  File "/src/util.py", line 68, in callback
    worker_function(eval(body))
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/context_managers.py", line 66, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/src/main.py", line 62, in worker
    updateMitb(out_file,  au['mitb_ptr'], au['AU_start_position'], au['AU_end_position'], au['dscn_value_ptr'])
KeyError: 'mitb_ptr'
```

The container compiles the "new" code I wrote to handle new data added by previous containers (encoder_my-pre-encoder, encoder_classificatore).
Since the aggregatore container does not receive new job, it fails to process the new code in the old data job.

aggregatore Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/.
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/.
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

The log 
In aggregatore/

```
$python main.py
2019-10-03 14:06:19,988 Could not get addresses to use: [Errno -2] Name or service not known (rabbit)
2019-10-03 14:06:19,988 Could not connect, 0 attempts left
2019-10-03 14:06:19,989 Connection open failed - gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    rabbit = Rabbit()
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/singleton_decorator/decorator.py", line 14, in __call__
    self._instance = self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/encoder/aggregatore/util.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBIT_HOST))
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 377, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 417, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 469, in _flush_output
    raise maybe_exception
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 176, in _adapter_connect
    socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_original/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 304, in _getaddrinfo
    return socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socktype, proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

bash into the container:

```
$docker exec -it encoder_aggregatore_1 bash
Error response from daemon: Container 72c3f5a2aa9caba040bc60d1608c193e250967cde1a2b68a74d47cf36be887ee is not running

$docker run -it encoder_aggregatore /bin/bash

root@d5d030d88f76:/src# python main.py
2019-10-03 13:30:30,864 Connection to 31.199.53.9:5672 failed: timeout
2019-10-03 13:30:30,864 Could not connect, 0 attempts left
2019-10-03 13:30:30,865 Connection open failed - 'Connection to 31.199.53.9:5672 failed: timeout'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    rabbit = Rabbit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/singleton_decorator/decorator.py", line 14, in __call__
    self._instance = self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/src/util.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBIT_HOST))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 377, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 417, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 471, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed(maybe_exception)
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 31.199.53.9:5672 failed: timeout
```

Comment: You need to add compose file, the failing container's logs. Try to manually start the failed containers and see the behavior.

Comment: Try bash into that container and run the command that it runs, manually and see what goes wrong when you do that.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja: I edited the question with what you asked for. Unfortunately it fails

Comment: Create a container from the image that the container that keeps crashing was created from:
```docker run -it  encoder_my-pre-encoder /bin/bash```
and then run the startup command that runs in that container.
Hope that makes sense. You should then see the error that keeps happening at startup of that container. That should help you solve the issue.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja: the container that is crashing is encoder_aggregatore_1.. Do you mean this container right? anyway I edited the question with what you asked for

Comment: My bad I meant ```docker run -it encoder_aggregatore /bin/bash``` since that is the image of the container that kept crashing. Do that and it should open a brand new container from the same image and then you should be able to debug the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja: I do have issues with the connection, any idea of what could have happen?

Comment: I don't have enough context to be able to answer that question.